# Firefox: how to scroll to top w/out short animation?

Tags: firefox

Last stable FireFox 23 (WinXP) has one irritating feature: when I'm at the page end and press Ctrl+Home, page is scrolled to the top not instantly, but with a short animation: like you hold the PgUp key, web page is flashing a little.

This's new and irritating feature. I want to instantly move to page start on pressing Ctrl+Home. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning off smooth scrolling will speed it up.

[image: Options Dialog, Advanced, General tab, Browsing section, Use smooth scrolling check box]